# My register form keeps refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

on my local server it works just fine but as soon as I take it live it starts only refershing the page instead of calling the validation.

This is my jquery:

```
<script>
    $("form#registerform").submit(
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            function validateForm() {
                var RegisterUsername = document.forms["contactForm"]["RegisterUsername"].value;
                var FirstName = document.forms["contactForm"]["FirstName"].value;
                var LastName = document.forms["contactForm"]["LastName"].value;
                var Email = document.forms["contactForm"]["Email"].value;
                var RegisterPassword = document.forms["contactForm"]["RegisterPassword"].value;


                if (RegisterUsername == null || RegisterUsername == "") {
                    $(".error-messages").text("Username required").fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
                    return false;
                }
                else if (FirstName == null || FirstName == "") {
                    $(".error-messages").text("First name required").fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
                    return false;
                } else if (LastName == null || LastName == "") {
                    $(".error-messages").text("Last name required").fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
                    return false;
                }
                else if (Email == null || Email == "") {
                    $(".error-messages").text("Email required").fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
                    return false;
                }
                else if (RegisterPassword == null || RegisterPassword == "") {
                    $(".error-messages").text("Password required").fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut(300);
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<form id="registerform" name="contactForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

    <div class="pl-land-input">
        <input class="email text-input" id="RegisterUsername" pattern=".{3,}" title="3 characters minimum" name="RegisterUsername" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="pl-land-input">
        <input class="email text-input" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="pl-land-input">
        <input class="email text-input" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="pl-land-input">
        <input class="email text-input" type="email" placeholder="Email"  name="Email" id="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="pl-land-input">
        <input class="email text-input" id="RegisterPassword" name="RegisterPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="signup-plland">Sign up</button>

</form>
```

I have been trying to get my head around it and kept customizing it but I couldn't figure out the problem there was no problem in console for calling the Jquery libs.

I hope I can solve this asap.

Comment: I reformatted your code and noticed a missing brace at the end of your javascript

Comment: This code is stating that you are defining the function each time you submit, instead of just calling that function, is the same code you have in the page you are making, or you just make it to show it here?

Comment: As @Pevara already mentioned you have a syntax error in your code. As of that your jQuery callback is not called and the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` will fail because the `validateForm` is not defined. If you fix the syntax error then the from will not refresh the page, but `validateForm` still won't be called.

Comment: @gaunt yeah it's the same code.  . however I am trying to name the funcation than call it.

Comment: @CTRL-In-Knowledge ok, didnt want to put this as an answer, but try it in your home, remove the html "onsubmit" on the element, change the place were you define the validation function, just put it outside of the on submit function, and inside the onsubmit jquery function put a call to the validation function, that should work. (no time currently, when i have it, i will make a fiddle for you)

Comment: I tried but it didn't seem to work. I guess I am still missing something.
I'll wait for the fiddle link to see how it looks like and see what I missed.